# Count of Non Formula Cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba, countif

lets say you had formulas in each cell between A1 & A9 but A10 had a hard coded number. Within VBA is there a formula you could enter in A11 that would give you the number 1 due to one record in the column having a value instead of a formula. (Or even a "False" would work in "A11" showing that column had 1 fail)?

Comment: No need for VBA. You can use Excel formula as shown below by @Atmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try 1 of the array formulas below (Validated with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

• Number of cells containing a formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(ISFORMULA(A1:A10),A1:A10))
```

• Number of cells NOT containing a formula (including empty cells):

```
=COUNT(IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A1:A10)),A1:A10))
```

• Number of cells NOT containing a formula (excluding empty cells):

```
=COUNT(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A10))*NOT(ISFORMULA(A1:A10)))>0,A1:A10))
```

Note you can also use the previous formula and `COUNTBLANK`

```
=COUNT(IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A1:A10)),A1:A10)) - COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)
```

• First row with a value instead of a formula:

```
=MIN(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A10))*NOT(ISFORMULA(A1:A10)))>0,ROW(A1:A10)))
```